# 7-zip archive with hard links?

Tags: archiving, tar, 7-zip, hardlink

I see that `tar` respects hard links

```
$ ln clonezilla.iso test.iso

$ tar cfvvJ archive.tar.xz *.iso

-rw-r--r-- Steven 111149056 2012-03-25 07:34 clonezilla.iso
hrw-r--r-- Steven         0 2012-03-25 07:34 test.iso link to clonezilla.iso
```

7-Zip does not do this

```
$ 7z a -mx=9 archive.7z *.iso

$ ls -l

-rw-r--r-- 1 Steven 212827496 Apr 17 07:40 archive.7z
-rw-r--r-- 1 Steven 105073772 Apr 17 07:38 archive.tar.xz
```

Is there a way to make 7-Zip respect hard links?

[gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/hard-links](http://gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/hard-links)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [7-zip v9.33 alpha](http://www.7-zip.org/history.txt), it is possible to keep hardlinks and symbolic links in the .tar and .wim formats. Those can then be compressed again with 7-zip.

Therefore: It is possible now, but requires an extra step.

Source: http://www.7-zip.org/history.txt

Comment: This is irrelevant to 7zip or the format.  Basically no.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation in the [7-Zip source code](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) doesn't mention hardlinks, nor does the [7z manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/7z.1.html), so it seems that it does not. (It does however support symlinks.)